# Explaining why $f(x)=\log_{1.1}(x)$ and $g(x)=x$ intersect in more than one point without using a calculator

Tags: calculus

> The functions $f(x)=\log_{1.1}(x)$ and  $g(x)=x$ are represented in
>   the picture below: [image]
>
> In this representation it can be seen one point of intersection of the
>   two functions.
>
> Without using the calculator, explain that that is not the only point
>   of intersection of the two functions.

My book says the solution is:

> The graphs have to intersect at least one more time because 
>   $$\lim_{x
> \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$$

What I don't understand exactly is the meaning of $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ in this context.

Is it some sort of ratio or perhaps diference than decreases as $x$ increases?

That would explain that, since this "ratio" gets smaller and in the picture $f(x)$ is greater than $g(x)$ after the intersection, $f(x)$ would have to decrease thus making this ratio decrease, until it becomes smaller than $g(x)$, therefore having to intersect it again.

Am I correct? Can someone explain to me better what $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ means in this context, or what this "ratio" represents exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to use base $e$ logarithms (they are the only I know !).

Consider the function $$f(x)=\frac{\log (x)}{\log \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)}-x$$ and its derivatives $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x \log \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)}-1 \qquad f''(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2 \log \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)}$$ The first derivative cancels at $$x_*=\frac{1}{\log \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)}\implies f(x_*)=-\frac{1+\log \left(\log \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)\right)}{\log
   \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)}\qquad f''(x_*)=-\log \left(\frac{11}{10}\right)$$ So, the point $x_*$ corresponds to a maximum (by the second derivative test) and then two roots to the equation $f(x)=0$ since $f(x_*)>0$.

**Edit**

If you make the problem more general for $f(x)=\log_a(x)-x$, the derivative will cancel at $x_*=\frac{1}{\log (a)}$ for which $f(x_*)=\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{\log (a)}\right)-1}{\log (a)}$ and there will be two roots if $f(x_*)>0$ that is to say if $a<e^{\frac{1}{e}} \approx 1.44467$.

Answer (score 1):

"since this "ratio" gets smaller and in the picture $f(x)$ is greater than $g(x)$ after the intersection, $f(x)$ would have to decrease thus making this ratio decrease, until it becomes smaller than $g(x)$, therefore having to intersect it again": you are correct as far as I can tell. When we say $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, we intuitively mean that $f(x)$ is much, *much* smaller than $g(x)$ in the long run and continues to get smaller in comparison as $x$ approaches larger values. In the rough figure, $f(x)$ is greater than $g(x)$, so it would have to eventually intersect and go below.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your initial intuition is a bad way of looking at it. If $\lim_{x
\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, then at some point it must be that $g(x) > f(x)$ (in the top left quadrant). Since $g(x) < f(x)$ in the diagram currently, then eventually, if the functions are continuous, they must intersect.

A slightly more formal way to think about this is by considering the function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ and considering its roots. We know $h(x) = 0$ at the point of intersection in the diagram and after this root, $h(x) > 0$. Also since $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$, we know at some point $g(x) > f(x)$ i.e $h(x) < 0$.

Since we have $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $h(x_1) > 0$ and $h(x_2) < 0$, by the [intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), there must be some point $x$ with $x_1 < x < x_2$ where $h(x) = 0$ or in other words, there must be some point where $f(x) = g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

One way to interpret your ratio and limit is that if that limit is 0, then $g(x)$ "grows faster" than $f(x)$. Have you heard your teacher use that language? If not, it more or less means that for a large values of $x$, $g(x)$ is much larger than $f(x)$.

With that in mind, your picture shows one intersection point. More important, you see that $f(x)$ is on top.

But now that you know that your limit implies $g(x)$ is eventually larger than $f(x)$, you can reason that there must be a point (off to the right, not seen on the picture) where $g(x)$ overtakes/crosses over/necessarily intersects $f(x)$.

Does that make any sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense